# Display two buttons side by side even on smaller screen devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display two buttons side by side cantered on smaller screen devices for a responsive website.

```html
<ul class="app-stores list-unstyled list-inline mx-auto mx-md-0 d-inline-block">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><img class="ios" src="img/appstore-apple.svg" alt="app-store"></a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><img class="android" src="img/appstore-android.svg" alt="google play"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and adjust the screen size according to your target device width. Then use a display of [`flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to make them side by side

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fortunee, Ive tried this but its not working. the buttons start to break line 812px going down. I've coppied this code from a bootstrap template by the way

Comment: Hey @premo this works on 600px width and below, you need to define the styles for your desired screen size. Also, make sure you target the element correctly. In the example code, I used the `ul` selector but to improve the specificity, you can include the class name too.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem lies in the two buttons not displaying correctly by your definition i.e. not side to side you may want to add a min-width attribute to your parent element otherwise known as container equal to the sum of the widths of the images.
Try putting this in your css file:

```
.btn-appstore { min-width: 200px }
```

where 200px is the supposed combined width of the two images